# Creating a new column based on range values provided in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, where one of the dataframe is as a reference table & the other contains actual values.

```
>>> reference_table
   MinRange  MaxRange  Multiplier Group
0        10        30           2     A
1        10        40           4     B
2        10        14          10     C
3        15        19           8     C
4        20        24           6     C

>>> df2
  Group  Element  Value
0     A       15      7
1     B       37      8
2     C       12      9
3     C       23     10
```

Here, I want to create a new column `Updated Value` in `data` dataframe as follows -

```
>>> data
  Group  Element  Value  Updated Value
0     A       15      7             14
1     B       37      8             32
2     C       12      9             90
3     C       23     10             60
```

Updated Value is created as follows -

Row 1: Element=15 & Group=A, which lies in the MinRange & MaxRange of reference table for Group A. Hence, Updated Value = Value*Multiplier = 7*2 = 14

Row 2: Element=37 & Group=B, which lies in the MinRange & MaxRange of reference table for Group B. Hence, Updated Value = Value*Multiplier = 8*4 = 32

Row 3: Element=12 & Group=C, which lies in the MinRange(10) & MaxRange(14) of reference table for **Group C(Index 2**). Hence, Updated Value = Value*Multiplier = 9*10 = 90

Row 4:  Element=23 & Group=C, which lies in the MinRange(10) & MaxRange(14) of reference table for **Group C(Index 4**). Hence, Updated Value = Value*Multiplier = 10*6 = 60

How to create such a column using pandas? I tried a few methods, but none of them worked. Happy to be pointed towards any reference or similar problem.

Comment: I've edited the question @ScottBoston

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution starting with `merge` and `query`:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Group')
res = res.query('MinRange <= Element <= MaxRange')
res['Updated Value'] = res['Value'] * res['Multiplier']
res = res[['Group', 'Element', 'Value', 'Updated Value']].reset_index(drop=True)

res
  Group  Element  Value  Updated Value
0     A       15      7             14
1     B       37      8             32
2     C       12      9             90
3     C       23     10             60
```

Comment: You can avoid query using `res[res["Element"].between(res["MinRange"], res["MaxRange"])]`

Comment: In case your `df`s are big you might consider using `dask` not changing anything on your code except `dd` instead of `pd` where `dd` comes from `import dask.dataframe as dd`.

Comment: @rpanai thanks, I didn't know about the `.between` method at all! I do like `query` in this case for its readability, as long as it is fast enough :P