# Creating a DataFrame from a dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, dictionary

I'm pretty new to Python and I have difficulties converting a dictionary to a DataFrame in Pyhton. 
My dictionary contains the probabilities for an up-movement of different stocks on different days. When I try to convert it into a DataFrame, the stock names are taken as column-names, which is just the way I want to have it. My problem is, that all the values appear in the first row of each column.

This is basically the code i tried to use:

At the beginning i have a sample of stocks like this:

```
stocks = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'AMZN']
```

To get the probabilities of an up-movement I used the following code:

```
proba = {stock: clf[stock].predict_proba(X_test[stock]) for stock in stocks}

print(proba)
```

gives me the following Output:

```
{'MSFT': array([[0.30994211],
   [0.15608782],
   [0.15608782],
   [0.16334815],
   [0.14721092],
   [0.29563944],
   [0.16334815],
   [0.24821587],
   [0.43182074],
   [0.30994211],
   [0.28825953],
   .
   .
   .
   [0.34160564]]), 'AAPL': array([[0.48241034],
   [0.47819121],
   [0.48937013],
   [0.49798732],
   [0.50132104],
   .
   .
   . 
   [0.03298367]]), 'AMZN': array([[0.51179782],
   [0.64532595],
   [0.56331474],
   [0.66499856],
   [0.55492011],
   [0.4623048 ],
   [0.4536123 ],
   [0.4613901 ],
   [0.39305493],
   [0.44297254],
   .
   .
   .])}
```

My goal is now to convert this dictionary into a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    MSFT    AAPL    AMZN
0   0.875   0.983   0.276
1   0.345   0.765   0.342
2   0.654   0.444   0.874  
    ...     ...     ...
    ...     ...     ...
```

In the end, the DataFrame should have 280 rows and 3 columns.

Here's a small sample to work with:

```
proba = {stock: clf[stock].predict_proba(X_test[stock]) for stock in stocks}
proba = {stock: np.delete(proba[stock], 0, axis=1) for stock in stocks}
print(proba)
```

The result is:

```
{'MSFT': array([[0.49784439],
   [0.51812552],
   [0.35948374]]), 'AAPL': array([[0.29038393],
   [0.58038393],
   [0.52032512]]), 'AMZN': array([[0.64295894],
   [0.54295894],
   [0.39719920]])}
```

These arrays should be converted to one DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     MSFT         AAPL         AMZN
0    0.49784439   0.29038393   0.64295894
1    0.51812552   0.58038393   0.54295894
2    0.35948374   0.52032512   0.39719920
```

Hopefully the edit made it a bit clearer.

Comment: Could you provide just the sample input & output. The code snippets you added don't run as expected. Maybe something in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894696/creating-a-new-column-based-on-range-values-provided-in-other-dataframe) format.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put the dict inside a list, just use `pandas.DataFrame(proba)`.
I would reccomed using the `DataFrame.from_dict` function which would give the same result with default params:

```
In [1]: import pandas
In [2]: d = {'a' : [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
In [3]: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
Out[3]:
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

But would also let you change the orientation of the dict, which I found quiet useful.
You can pass `orient` to the function if your dict keys are your index column. You will probably want to use columns as well to name your columns:

```
In [4]: pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['first','second','hird'])
Out[4]:
   first  second  hird
a      1       2     3
b      4       5     6
c      7       8     9
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tries using **pandas.DataFrame(proba)** as well, but then the error 
**ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index**
appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Convert list of lists into list
for key in res.keys():
     res[key] = [x for sublist in res[key] for x in sublist]

# Read dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(res)
```

You must convert your list of lists into a single list before working on converting it into a DataFrame.

Comment: i already tried using `DataFrame.from_records()`
Unfortunately you solution raises the same error as above:
`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: @TomRoider I see you have significantly changed your question since the last time. Provide a short sample data that we can work with.

Comment: I provided a short sample, hope it helps